# Ant/JUnit - How to assert package dependencies/non-dependencies?

Tags: java, ant, junit, dependencies

Is there a code analysis tool for Java for asserting package dependencies/non-dependencies?

I have a project where dependencies have crept in between packages that should not know about each other - in particular back-dependencies, which should have been one way.

I'd like to specify which pairs of packages (in which direction) are allowed to be dependent.  Alternatively, specifying packages that are NOT allowed to depend on each other - or not both ways - would help.  Ideally this would be something that could run as part of an Ant build and/or JUnit run and fail the build if new dependencies, in violation of the rules, are introduced.  We'd then add this to our CI process.

It would also be useful to be able to specify dependencies at the level of groups of packages (for example, all packages and sub-packages in 'web' CAN depend on any package in 'api' or its sub-packages).

Some specifics in case relevant, for my particular project:

- The Java version is 1.7
- The build process is based around Ant (can upgrade to latest version if needed)
- Testing is with JUnit (can upgrade to latest version if needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a solution like [Jdepend](http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html). There is an example on how to [use with junit](http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html#junit)

Comment: Still haven't had a chance to test that JDepend does what I need - though it looks like it will.  As it looks good and I haven't found a better choice, I've accepted this answer.